# Getting results from a table, storing them in an Array then displaying them

Tags: c#, mysql

I've been trying to fix this for quite a while now but I can wrap my head around what the exact problem is here.
I have a table that has ID, first_name and surname. I'm trying to pull a row from this table, store it in an array then display it in a listbox. Here's what I've got

```
        public Contacts[] getAllContacts()
    {
        List<Contacts> theContactList = new List<Contacts>();

        try
        {

            conn = new MySqlConnection(cs);
            conn.Open();

            string stm = "select id, first_name, surname from contacts";
            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(stm, conn);
            rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            while (rdr.Read())
            {
                Contacts theContact = new Contacts();
                theContact.contactID = rdr.GetInt32("id");
                theContact.first_name = rdr.GetString("first_name");
                theContact.surname = rdr.GetString("surname");

                theContactList.Add(theContact);

            }
        }
        catch (MySqlException ex)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Error: {0}", ex.ToString());
        }
        finally
        {
            if (rdr != null)
            {
                rdr.Close();
            }

            if (conn != null)
            {
                conn.Close();
            }

        }
        if (theContactList.Count > 0)
        {
            return theContactList.ToArray();
        }
        else
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

This is the method im using to pull the values, now in another class I'm using this to display the values into the listbox.

```
        ContactManager contactMan = new ContactManager();
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        reloadContacts();
    }




    private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (listBox1.SelectedIndex > 0)
        {
            Contacts currentContact = (Contacts)listBox1.SelectedItem;

            textBox1.Text = currentContact.contactID.ToString();
            textBox2.Text = currentContact.surname;
            textBox3.Text = currentContact.first_name;


        }
    }

    private void reloadContacts()
    {
        listBox1.Items.Clear();
        Contacts[] allContacts = contactMan.getAllContacts();


        foreach (Contacts b in allContacts)
        {
            listBox1.Items.Add(b);

        }

}
```

Now the thing that's really confusing me is what's being displayed. I've been changing my table around and I've found that in the list box it will display "ProjectName.Contacts" for each row, but the first entry in the list box won't display any info when it's selected, whereas the others do.

Any help on how to fix this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The `ListBox` will display any object you put into it by using the `ToString()` method of that object. If you do not override this method, it will return the class name for custom classes. This is what happened.

You need to decide what you want to display. Start by using `listBox1.Items.Add(b.surname);` to see that your data is there. Work with format strings to produce better results or use a `ListView` to have columns for your data.

Comment: Thanks, I added an override method since I want to play around a bit with this listBox.

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem is here:

```
if (listBox1.SelectedIndex > 0)
{
    Contacts currentContact = (Contacts)listBox1.SelectedItem;

     textBox1.Text = currentContact.contactID.ToString();
     textBox2.Text = currentContact.surname;
     textBox3.Text = currentContact.first_name;
}
```

SelectedIndex = -1 is unselected.  0 is the first element.  Try:

```
if (listBox1.SelectedIndex != -1)
{
```

Comment: Thanks, I just changed it to > -1, this should provide the same results as != -1, correct?

Comment: Yes - there is no circumstance that you can end up with -2